How to install multiple virtual cameras on Windows?
I want to install multiple virtual webcams on Windows. I want to launch multiple instances of video chatting websites and play video file using virtual cameras. So, I want as many virtual cameras as possible.
Specify any tool that I can use to install virtual webcams.

There is a limit to each software and the number will also depend on your hardware.  Please specifiy your hardware.

Can I have atleast 5 to 10 cameras

@RohitGupta My system is Intel i5 - 4th generation with 8 gb of ram.
